# My Apps was removed by Google, we resubmit and keep rejected because did not match declared core functionality

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Recently Our Apps got remove by Google because we use 3rd party plugin that take sensitive data.

We had take out that plugin and try to submit again in beta
but our apps keep rejected

> Publishing status: Rejected
>   After review, your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>   Issue: Violation of Permissions policy  After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
>
> Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality {Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)}. Please remove these permissions from your app.
>
> Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.
>
> We couldn’t verify your privacy policy. If your app requests permissions and handles sensitive user data, you need to post a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console and the app itself. Your privacy policy must comprehensively disclose how your app collects, uses, and shares user data. Please add or update your privacy policy in order to comply with Developer Program Policies.

Declared Core Functionality form is mandatory / required but we couldn't found core functionality to be filled

as you can see our apps required permission looks like this

[image: permission]

and declare core functionality form looks like this
[image]

Could somebody help us ?? please enlighten us..

Comment: it seems your app declares having access to things it does not use. So the answer is to declare the actual things you need to access in your app (the least needed) and re-submit it after completing the form of google-play

Comment: Actually our apps dont use any function in core functionality. Our apps just use internet connection. But core functionality is required and must be filled. we already try check only one (default sms handler) and rejected. we try to check them all and rejected again.. :(

Comment: @Rendi, I am facing the same issue, did you find the fix?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might have an old version of your app still active on an Alpha or Beta channel, that's why you have to fill in the form. If you remove the app on the Alpha or Beta channel, will it let you publish then?

Comment: We had an old version in production, the new one still in beta channel. Should we remove the old version in production?? how can we do it ?

Comment: If you don't want to fill in the form, then you need to remove all the old versions. Just publish your new version to production and beta.

Comment: could you inform us how could we remove the production version ?? we dont found any delete button at playstore

Comment: I didn't mean remove. I meant replace it with your newer version without the permissions.